# PLSQL package that create simple excel file w/ multiplesheet inside and send directly to email as attachment, without using UTL

Tags: excel, oracle, plsql, package, smtp

I am new to PLSQL Development,

Hope the experts can help me.

is there a simple way to create an excel file from PLSQL procedure or package and email directly it as an attachment w/out saving to server?

the requirement is this,

1. Only one excel workbook
2. then, the first query output will be on the first excelSheet (select 1,2,3 from dual)
3. then, the second query output will be on the second excelsheet(select z,y,x from dual)
4. then email the excel file using SMTP as an attachment.

prefer not to use UTL, since it requires saving the file. and I have limited privileges using directories in our DB.

I just need to email it directly as an excel file to the user.

Thanks,
From a Guy that badly needs help since this guy is a noob and still starting to learn PLSQ. :)

Comment: Simple, probably not.  There are Java libraries that can generate Excel files with multiple sheets.  You can load one of those in the database and create a Java stored procedure that generates the Excel file and then email that out.

Comment: Useful library at https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils